# Inequality of differential equation implies inequality of functions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f,g: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be differentiable,$$f '(x) = h(x,f(x))$$ and $$g '(x)< h(x,g(x))$$
with $h:G\subset \mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R$.

Show that if $f(a) > g(a)$ then $f(x)>g(x)$ for every $x$.

Comment: The second equation should probably be $g'(x) \lt h(x, g(x))$ ? Otherwise trivally $f'(x) = h(x, f(x)) \gt g'(x)$ so that $f - g$ is increasing on $[a, b]$.

Comment: Right, thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the conclusion is wrong, i.e. $f(a) > g(a)$ and $f(x) \le g(x)$ for some $x$. $f$ and $g$ are continuous, so there must be a $c \in (a, b]$ such that
$$
 f(c) = g(c) \text{ and } f(x) > g(x) \text{ for } a \le x \lt c
$$

Now
$$
  f'(c) - g'(c) \gt h(c, f(c)) - h(c, g(c)) = 0
$$

On the other hand, $f(x) - g(x) \gt 0 = f(c) - g(c)$ for $a \le x \lt c$ implies 
$f'(c) - g'(c) \le 0$.
This is a contradiction.

*Remark:* The conditions on this *differential inequality* can be relaxed to
$g'(x) \le h(x, g(x))$, see for example http://www.mth.msu.edu/~sen/Math_848/lec_6s.pdf.