# $\frac{da}{dt} \leq f(a(t))$ and $\frac{db}{dt}=f(b(t))$ imply $a(t) \leq b(t)$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ be nonnegative real-valued differentiable functions and $f$ be a strictly positive continuous function.

If $a(0)=b(0)$, $\frac{da}{dt} \leq f(a(t))$ and $\frac{db}{dt}=f(b(t))$ for $t \geq 0$. Then how do I show that $a(t) \leq b(t)$ for $t \geq 0$?

It seems intuitively clear but very tricky to prove....I cannot compare $f(a(t))$ and $f(b(t))$ directly. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See 
https://users.math.msu.edu/users/sen/Math_848/lec_6s.pdf

[Inequality of differential equation implies inequality of functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799085/inequality-of-differential-equation-implies-inequality-of-functions/799298)

Comment: Could you help me with the problem in the link as well?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3632210/invariant-interval-for-ode-implies-invariant-interval-for-parabolic-pde

Comment: I'm afraid not...